# Optimal cut-off value for continuous covariate with binary outcome

Tags: logistic, roc, optimal

Research question: What is the optimal cut-off value for a continuous covariate (age) with a binary outcome (suitable or not for a certain treatment). I realize that we lose information by dichotomizing the variable but we the aim is to use this cut-off value in clinic.

I intended to use ROC curve analysis or logistic regression. What would you recommend or do you have any other suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Don't bin your continuous data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/68834/1352). Feed them into your algorithm as-is; potentially transform them using (e.g.) restricted cubic splines (see, e.g., Frank Harrell's *Regression Modeling Strategies*) to capture any nonlinearity.

Comment: See  [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61521/cut-off-point-in-a-roc-curve-is-there-a-simple-function/82801#82801) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142954/getting-the-optimal-age-cut-off?rq=1)